# Flutter add item to list

Tags: list, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to add an item to a list:

```
void submitAll() async {
List<UserSearchItem> userSearchItems = [];
Firestore.instance
    .collection('insta_users')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) =>
    data.documents.forEach((doc){
      print(data.documents.length);

      User user = new User.fromDocument(doc);
      UserSearchItem searchItem = new UserSearchItem(user);
      userSearchItems.add(searchItem);
      print(user.bio);

    }));
print("Loaded");
print(userSearchItems.length);
}
```

But if I print the length of the list to the console, it always says, the list is 0 long...

```
print(userSearchItems.length);
```

Any suggegstions?

Best Regards

Comment: Does using `setState(() {});` around the `userSearchItems.add(...)’ help?

Comment: No that does not work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I will try to give an explanation of what is happing here take a look on this code:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  List<int> userSearchItems = [];

  Timer _sendTimeOutTimer;

  const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 2);
  _sendTimeOutTimer = Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) {
    userSearchItems.add(1);
    print(userSearchItems.length); // result 1 and it will be executed after 2 seconds 
    _sendTimeOutTimer.cancel();
  });

  print(userSearchItems.length); // result 0 and it will be executed first
}
```

The print inside asynchronous action(Timer) it will be executed after 2 seconds means after the asynchronous action ends but the one which is outside of asynchronous action(Timer) it will be executed directly without waiting 2 seconds, in your case the asynchronous action is listening to data `.listen((data) =>`, so if you print the length outside of your asynchronous action you will not see the deferent because the item is not added yet.

Solution: you can create function witch return `Future` and then wait until it's finished then print the length.

```
List<UserSearchItem> userSearchItems = [];

Future<String> submitAll() async {

Firestore.instance
    .collection('insta_users')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) =>
    data.documents.forEach((doc){
      print(data.documents.length);

      User user = new User.fromDocument(doc);
      UserSearchItem searchItem = new UserSearchItem(user);
      userSearchItems.add(searchItem);
      print(user.bio);

      return 'success';
    }));
}

void yourFunction() async{
   await submitAll();
   print("Loaded");
   print(userSearchItems.length);
}
```

Then call `yourFunction()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! When I try your improved code it throws "The await expression can only be used in asynchronous funtion." Any Idea? Thank you!

Comment: Wrap everything inside an async function, I already update the code example.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But now I get another error: "[Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null." Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes of course because `userSearchItems ` should be declared outside of `submitAll` function so it can be accessed from `yourFunction`, I update the code.

Comment: Ok so this error disappeard :) But it occured another one: "Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null." Sorry for bothering you, but it seems you know what you're talking about!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `print(userSearchItems.length);` inside forEach after adding the item and you will see the real length.

Comment: This works, but is there no solution outside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way tu add new data tu a list on Flutter.

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    double newValue=newValue+1; //This is just an example,you should put what you'r trying to add here.
    list[i]["newValueName"] = newValue; //This is how we add the new value tu the list,
  }
```

See if it work by doing a:

```
print(list);//You can put a breakpoint her to see it more clearly
```

Hope it helps.